# how to reload the store in ext js 4.1?

Tags: extjs4.1

how to reload the store values in ext js 4.1 ?

```
var user_date_wise = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['MS', 'HSD', 'XP', 'XM','comp_date'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'php/data.php?item='+date
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user_date_wise.load()
```

See [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load).